# CheckBox column property

Tags: database, vb.net, checkbox

I have created a `CheckBox` in VB.Net.
I have also created a `CheckBox` column in one of my database's tables.

I want to assign a `Boolean` value to it, meaning, if the `CheckBox` is checked the column value should be `1` in the database, And if it's not checked, the column value should be `0` in the database.

Could you please guide me, so that I'm able to add this property to the `CheckBox` column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly are you struggling with? If you expect us to write the code for you, this is not how SO works. If you have a _specific_ problem, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52543377/edit) your question to include your code and explain the problem so the community can help you with it. Moreover, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Generally speaking, you simply save a `Boolean` value, i.e. `True` or `False` to the database in the same way you would save a `String`, a number or a `Date`.  You would get that value from the `Checked` property of the `CheckBox`.  It's just straight ADO.NET, just as for any other data.  If you already know how to write ADO.NET code then you know what to do already.  If you don't know how to write ADO.NET code then that's what you need to learn.  If and when you encounter a specific issue, post all the details relevant to that issue, including your current code.